# Google Geocoder / Javascript: How to send a broad search

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

My broad goal is to generate a list of all Baptist churches within 100 miles of a given town.

On Google Maps, I can type in "Baptist in NC" and I get a map covered in little red dots, each of which is a location with the word "Baptist" in the name.

I want to create a table of all those results, with formatted addresses and lat/lng.

The way I've been trying to go about it is to use a Geocode request passing "Baptist in NC" as the address.  I figured I could then go in afterward and cross-check all the distances from the center of the town I'm looking for.

```
function returnChurches() {
  sAddr = "Baptist in NC";
  dOut = document.getElementById("divChurchList");
  dOut.innerHTML = "";
  myGeocoder.geocode({'address':sAddr}, 
    function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        // alert(results[0].geometry.location);
        // alert(results.length);
        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          dOut.innerHTML += results[i].formatted_address + "<br>";
          mrkrIdx = mrkrChurch.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position:results[i].geometry.location, title:results[i].formatted_address, icon:pinImageClient, myField:results[i].formatted_address
          }));
        }
        for (i in mrkrChurch) {
          google.maps.event.addListener(mrkrChurch[i], 'click', fChurch(mrkrChurch[i], mrkrChurch[i].myField, map));
        };
        map.setCenter(results[i - 1].geometry.location);
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Unfortunately, this is only giving me about 15 "Baptist" locations around Raleigh (Raleigh is the capital of NC).  I want the full list that returns when you put in "Baptist in NC" on Google Maps.

Does anyone know of a way to get that full list?  Some other function or library?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The [Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) is for finding *addresses*.  "Baptist in NC", is not a address.

You probably want the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places).  However, that is limited to 60 results (in 3 groups of 20) (for [NearbySearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests)) or 200 results (for [RadarSearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests)).

[looks like 200 isn't going to cut it for North Carolina](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_place-radar-search_form.html)